# SQL - Different sum levels in one select with where clause

Tags: sql, select, sum

I have 2 tables.  One has the orginal amount that remains static.  The second table has a list of partial amounts applied over time against the orginal amount in the first table.

DB Tables:

```
***memotable***
ID [primary, unique]
Amount (Orginal Amount)

***transtable***
ID [many IDs in transtable to single ID in memotable] 
AmountUsed (amount applied)
ApplyDate (date applied)
```

I would like to find, in a single select, the ID, amount used since last week (ApplyDate > 2011-04-21), amount used to date.

The only rows that should appear in the result is when an amount has been used since last week (ApplyDate > 2011-04-21).

I'm stuck on trying to get the sum for the amount used to date, since that needs to include AmountUsed values that are outside of when ApplyDate > 2011-04-21.

Comment: SELECT A.ID, 
A.Amount, 
SUM(B.AmountUsed) AS AmountUsedWeek, 
(SELECT SUM(B.AmountUsed) AS AmountUSedTotal FROM transtable C WHERE A.ID = C.ID) 
FROM memotable A, transtable B 
WHERE B.ApplyDate > '2011-02-07' AND A.ID = B.D 
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to avoid subselects in this case:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  AmountUsedSinceLastWeek = SUM(CASE WHEN ApplyDate > '4/21/2011' THEN AmountUsed END)
  AmountUsedToDate = SUM(AmountUsed)
FROM TransTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I thought this would give me extra rows (those <= 4/21/2011), but it does not!  It looks like this is the better way to go.  Out of curisoity, I wonder how I would show all rows.

Comment: @brennt: Sorry, I don't follow. `AmountUsedToDate = SUM(AmountUsed)` – I thought that was summing all rows. Or what did you mean?

Comment: Your solution is correct.  It correctly shows only the rows where amounts were applied for the past week, while also showing the overall totals.  I was just wondering why it does this, rather than showing all the rows for all time.

Comment: @brennt: The partial sum is calculated with the help of CASE. So the first SUM in this query is not applied to the `AmountUsed` column directly, but to the result of the CASE expression. And the CASE expression returns only those values of `AmountUsed` whose corresponding `ApplyDate` values are the dates after '4/21/2011', otherwise NULL is returned (which is ignored by SUM). If you run this query without grouping and aggregating, you will be able to see the 'raw' data and so you will see for yourself what the CASE expression is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to limit it to rows that happened since last week, but also want to include the total to date, I think the most efficient method would be to use sub-selects...

```
SELECT
    lastWeek.ID,
    lastWeek.AmountUsedSinceLastWeek,
    toDate.AmountUsedToDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        SUM(AmountUsed) AS AmountUsedSinceLastWeek
    FROM TransTable
    WHERE ApplyDate > '4/21/2011'
    GROUP BY ID
) lastWeek JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        SUM(AmountUsed) AS AmountUsedToDate
    FROM TransTable
    GROUP BY ID
) toDate ON lastWeek.ID = toDate.ID
```